# Kotlin Coroutines, ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to convert the code provided as an example [TDLib Java Example](https://github.com/tdlib/td/blob/master/example/java/org/drinkless/tdlib/example/Example.java) to Kotlin Coroutines. And I ran into some problems that I can't fix.

In the code snippet below, when the application is launched, it sometimes crashes with a Concurrency exception

```
private val chats: ConcurrentHashMap<Long, TdApi.Chat> = ConcurrentHashMap()
private val mainChatList: NavigableSet<OrderedChat> = TreeSet()

suspend fun load(limit: Int) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    awaitAll(
        async {
            telegramRepository.loadChats(limit)
        },
        async {
            telegramRepository.newChatFlow
                .onEach { chat ->
                    chats[chat.id] = chat
                    val positions = chat.positions.clone()
                    chat.positions = arrayOfNulls(0)
                    
                    setChatPositions(chat, positions)
                }.collect()
        },
        async {
            telegramRepository.chatLastMessageFlow
                .onEach { updateChat ->
                    val chat = chats[updateChat.chatId]
                    if (chat != null) {
                        chat.lastMessage = updateChat.lastMessage
                        
                        setChatPositions(chat, updateChat.positions)
                    }
                }.collect()
        },
        async {
            telegramRepository.chatPositionFlow
                .onEach { updateChat ->
                    val chat = chats[updateChat.chatId]
                    if (chat != null) {
                        var i = 0
                        for (k in chat.positions.indices) {
                            if (chat.positions[k].list.constructor == TdApi.ChatListMain.CONSTRUCTOR) {
                                break
                            }
                            i++
                        }
                        val newPositions = arrayOfNulls<TdApi.ChatPosition>(
                            size = chat.positions.size + (if (updateChat.position.order == 0L) 0 else 1)
                                    - (if (i < chat.positions.size) 1 else 0)
                        )
                        var pos = 0
                        if (updateChat.position.order != 0L) {
                            newPositions[pos++] = updateChat.position
                        }
                        for (j in chat.positions.indices) {
                            if (i != j) {
                                newPositions[pos++] = chat.positions[j]
                            }
                        }
                        assert(pos == newPositions.size)
                        
                        setChatPositions(chat, newPositions)
                    }
                }.collect()
        }
    )
}

private fun setChatPositions(chat: TdApi.Chat, positions: Array<TdApi.ChatPosition?>) {
    //TODO: Concurrency exception
    for (position in chat.positions) {
        if (position.list.constructor == TdApi.ChatListMain.CONSTRUCTOR) {
            val isRemoved = mainChatList.remove(OrderedChat(chat.id, position))
            assert(isRemoved)
        }
    }
    chat.positions = positions
    for (position in chat.positions) {
        if (position.list.constructor == TdApi.ChatListMain.CONSTRUCTOR) {
            val isAdded: Boolean = mainChatList.add(OrderedChat(chat.id, position))
            assert(isAdded)
        }
    }
}

fun getData() = flow {
    //TODO: Concurrency exception
    while (true) {
        val chats = mainChatList.map { orderedChat ->
            val chat = chats[orderedChat.chatId]!!
            Chat(
                id = chat.id,
                title = chat.title.ifEmpty { "Deleted account" },
                photo = chat.photo?.let {
                    ProfilePhoto(
                        thumbnail = chat.photo!!.minithumbnail!!.data,
                        file = chat.photo!!.small
                    )
                },
                isPinned = orderedChat.position.isPinned,
                unreadCount = chat.unreadCount,
                lastMessage = chat.lastMessage
            )
        }.toList()
        emit(chats)
        delay(1000L)
    }
}

data class OrderedChat (
    val chatId: Long,
    val position: TdApi.ChatPosition
)
```

As I understand it, this happens at the moment when my ViewModel receives data through the `getData()` method and at the same moment, the `setChatPositions()` method is called in parallel which modifies the `mainChatList` elements.

However, due to my poor experience with Coroutines, I do not understand how it can be synchronized. Any help with refactoring the above code is also accepted, I'm sure I made enough mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coroutine synchronization is done using Mutex. Create a Mutex property and use it `withLock { }` around the code that modifies or iterates your `mainChatList`.

```
private val mainChatListMutex = Mutex()

// ...

private fun setChatPositions(chat: TdApi.Chat, positions: Array<TdApi.ChatPosition?>) {
    //TODO: Concurrency exception
    for (position in chat.positions) {
        if (position.list.constructor == TdApi.ChatListMain.CONSTRUCTOR) {
            val isRemoved = mainChatListMutex.withLock { 
                mainChatList.remove(OrderedChat(chat.id, position)) 
            }
            assert(isRemoved)
        }
    }
    chat.positions = positions
    for (position in chat.positions) {
        if (position.list.constructor == TdApi.ChatListMain.CONSTRUCTOR) {
            val isAdded: Boolean = mainChatListMutex.withLock { 
                mainChatList.add(OrderedChat(chat.id, position))
            }
            assert(isAdded)
        }
    }
}

fun getData() = flow {
    //TODO: Concurrency exception
    while (true) {
        val chats = mainChatListMutex.withLock { 
                mainChatList.map { orderedChat ->
                val chat = chats[orderedChat.chatId]!!
                Chat(
                    id = chat.id,
                    title = chat.title.ifEmpty { "Deleted account" },
                    photo = chat.photo?.let {
                        ProfilePhoto(
                            thumbnail = chat.photo!!.minithumbnail!!.data,
                            file = chat.photo!!.small
                        )
                    },
                    isPinned = orderedChat.position.isPinned,
                    unreadCount = chat.unreadCount,
                    lastMessage = chat.lastMessage
                )
            }
        }
        emit(chats)
        delay(1000L)
    }
}
```

---

How to do this reactively instead of wasting resource by preemptively checking over and over, and to avoid the unnecessary use of `!!`. I can't fix the `!!` after `minithumbnail` because I don't know how your ProfilePhoto class works. I don't know why you are able to consider it safe to use `!!` here.

```
private val chatsChangedFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Unit>(replay = 1).apply {
    tryEmit(Unit)
}

// Call chatsChangedFlow.tryEmit(Unit) whenever you change the underlying data.

val data = chatsChangedFlow.map {
    mainChatListMutex.withLock { 
        mainChatList.map { orderedChat ->
            val chat = chats.getValue(orderedChat.chatId)
            Chat(
                id = chat.id,
                title = chat.title.ifEmpty { "Deleted account" },
                photo = chat.photo?.let { 
                    ProfilePhoto(
                        thumbnail = it.minithumbnail!!.data,
                        file = it.small
                    )
                },
                isPinned = orderedChat.position.isPinned,
                unreadCount = chat.unreadCount,
                lastMessage = chat.lastMessage
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And how efficiently is my getData() function written? How is the best way to pass a list through a flow?

Comment: Efficiency-wise it’s fine. If the list is really big you could tag it with `.flowOn(Dispatchers.Default)` to make sure the work is done off the main thread. The use of `!!` is pretty ugly. You already used `?.let` so there’s no reason to retrieve the nullable `chat.photo` again inside the let scope. When retrieving from a Map where you know the value exists, use `.getValue()` instead of `[]!!` for better error messaging in case you were wrong.

Comment: But in my opinion, it is very hacky to use a while loop to keep checking preemptively for changes and doing the conversion unnecessarily if there weren’t changes. The proper way to do it would be to trigger it to emit reactively when changes actually happen. But this requires more setup of course. You could use a private `MutableSharedFlow<Unit>` as a backing flow and emit to it when changes are made. Map it to your `Flow<List<Chat>>` in the `getData()` function. But I would change `getData()` to a property to follow Kotlin convention. Getter functions without parameters should be properties.

Comment: Yes, but using the while loop is the only example I could find. Could you provide a small example of using `MutableSharedFlow<Unit>`?
As for the usage `!!` in this case, this is the only way not to receive warnings, even though I used the construction `?.let`. «Smart cast to `TdApi.ChatPhotoInfo` is impossible, because `chat.photo` is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time»

Comment: See edit. You're using `?.let` incorrectly.

Comment: I tried using your example with `MutableSharedFlow` however nothing works. Inside `chatsChangedFlow.map{...}` unable to call `emit(chats)`

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to change that. It should just be `chats`. Or we can just drop the variable altogether, and the inner `map` expression becomes the return value. Fixed it.